# Jquery image slider/gallery for images of different sizes

Tags: jquery, image-gallery

I have a few different sized images that I would like to display in a simple jquery gallery with forward and back navigation.

Is there a jquery plugin that is made for this? Most of the ones I find are made for images that are the same size.

Thanks!

Comment: +1: I had the exact same problem a while back. If I solve it (I'll write my own carousel), I'll let you know!

Comment: please do! i can't believe it doesn't exist.

Comment: Look at this gallery, that i wrote few days ago. It very similar to what google use: https://github.com/creotiv/jquery-photowall

Comment: This one support it, might be handy http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/gallery/ but note that it's not free for commercial usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always the standard style gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Try these ones:

- [Jquery LightBox Clone](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#!prettyPhoto%5Bpp_gal%5D/3/)
- [Sliding Gallery](http://www.meadmiracle.com/SlidingGallery.aspx)

But there are tons of other ones

Answer (score 0):

FancyBox FTW :) http://fancybox.net/

Comment: Sorry but FancyBox is not a slider.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this - really nice carousel and gives you all the code you need:

http://brenelz.com/blog/creating-a-3d-carousel-from-scratch/

or this

http://blarnee.com/wp/jquery-image-carousels-for-slidehow/comment-page-1/